# Portable Class Libraries & WebRequest.ContentLength

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, portable-class-library

I have a Portable Class Library that targets ".NET for Windows Store apps" and "Windows Phone 7.5 or higher".  I make HTTP POST requests and as of last week, the admins in charge of the back-end decided that I need to send a ContentLength of 0 as opposed to -1 that is defaulted by .NET.  I use the WebRequest class but i'm flexible enough to use HttpWebRequest if needed.

Normally I would just use WebRequest.Create and set the ContentLength property.  In the PCL library, the ContentLength property is not available.  If I try to add a Header with a key of "Content-Length" the framework complains that I should just use the ContentLength property.

Any ideas on how I can set the ContentLength in a PCL?

Comment: What if you  BeginGetRequestStream() and EndGetRequestStream() without writing anything in the middle? It should be a 0 length stream (and it may force the ContentLength in the header).

Comment: Can you put that as an answer?

That actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can't set the `ContentLength` property but it must be set to 0 you may try to call `GetRequestStream` (or `BeginGetRequestStram` followed by `EndGetRequestStream`) without writing anything to the `Stream` itself, this should update `ContentLength` property to its actual value (0, because nothing has be written).

Comment: I spend some time figuring this out. Thanks for your answer! The solution is sometimes so simple :-).